# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Ask Different breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  5         31
Users destroyed                                 582          0
Users deleted                                     5          0
Users contacted                                  38          0
User suspensions lifted early                     1          0
User banned from review                           1          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue         1,675      3,399
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue              254        675
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue        513      2,666
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue            1,242      2,564
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue             3,373      8,054
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue            1,477      3,328
Tags merged                                     169          0
Tag synonyms proposed                            10          1
Tag synonyms created                              9          0
Revisions redacted                                7          0
Questions unprotected                            11          0
Questions reopened                              260          2
Questions protected                              92        441
Questions migrated                               45          1
Questions merged                                 12          0
Questions flagged⁴                              522      8,757
Questions closed                              2,189        479
Question flags handled⁴                       2,611      6,668
Posts unlocked                                    6         10
Posts undeleted                                 104        186
Posts locked                                     15      2,060
Posts deleted⁵                                3,687     10,981
Posts bumped                                      0      8,728
Escalations to the CM team                        3          0
Comments undeleted                               39          0
Comments flagged                                201      2,632
Comments deleted⁶                             3,805      5,276
Comment flags handled                         1,110      1,723
Bounties canceled                                 1          0
Answers flagged                                 518      6,825
Answer flags handled                          6,541        802
All comments on a post moved to chat             44          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Answer (score 10):

This is a wonderful summary and shows in plain data how much everyone does to moderate this site past those of us with a diamond granting a couple of the more formal moderation tools. I am humbled by the overwhelming goodwill people bring to this site to help each other and make a place to answer questions people have about Apple services and products.

Thanks to the employees that created this tool and system of governance and built tolerance, respect, clarity and accountability into the moderation tools. There's quite a large team that backs us up as users and moderators of the site.

Happy 2019 to everyone!