# 2019: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
>   -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges 
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together. 
And what could be more festive than a big pile of numbers? 
So here is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Ask Different over the past 12 months:

```
                  Action                  Moderators Community¹
----------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                   8         24
Users destroyed³                                 122          0
Users deleted                                      2          0
Users contacted                                   42          0
Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue          1,318      2,137
Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue               303        393
Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue         483      1,379
Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue               573      1,933
Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue              2,197      7,537
Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue             1,463      1,510
Tags merged                                      204          0
Tag synonyms proposed                              9          0
Tag synonyms created                              10          0
Tag highlight language set                        11          0
Revisions redacted                                18          0
Questions unprotected                              9          0
Questions reopened                               301          6
Questions protected                               96        236
Questions migrated                                53          0
Questions merged                                   5          0
Questions flagged⁵                               255      2,731
Questions closed                               2,200        258
Question flags handled⁵                        1,361      1,625
Posts unlocked                                    10         14
Posts undeleted                                   80        171
Posts locked                                      17        997
Posts deleted⁶                                 2,169      9,069
Posts bumped                                       0      1,462
Escalations to the Community Manager team          1          0
Comments undeleted                                30          0
Comments flagged                                 171      3,832
Comments deleted⁷                              4,447      6,874
Comment flags handled                            857      3,145
Bounties canceled                                  1          0
Answers flagged                                  743      4,588
Answer flags handled                           5,074        257
All comments on a post moved to chat              40          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. [Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁵ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

#### Further reading:

- Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? I posted a similar report here last year: [2018: a year in moderation](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3443/2018-a-year-in-moderation)...
- You can also check out [this report on other sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222019%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)
- Or peruse [detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341507/2019-a-year-in-closing)

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: Why did you cross post this across all of the meta sites?

Comment: Each post's numbers are specific to that meta's main site, @asadefa

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Comment: I wish that you didn't get fired

Answer (score 6):

Thank you @shog9 for your many years of service here. You were instrumental to me learning the ropes as I joined the sites and got adjusted to what it means to serve as one of the moderators here - first by reputation and then after election.

- [Thank you, Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342031/thank-you-shog9)

Thanks specifically the kind words, encouragement, humor and humanity you brought to the concept of community and elected volunteer moderation here.

It will be sad to not have you pop in here every so ofter to drop a wisdom nugget or data about how the site works.

I wish you great success and new opportunities that [await you in 2020](https://twitter.com/shog9/status/1216752358933184512).

Comment: Thanks bmike - appreciate it